# iPhone bundle display and local notification title

Tags: iphone, apple-push-notifications

Is the title for a notification (push or local) always the bundle display name?  I have shortened the bundle display name, but would like the local notifications to display the full bundle name.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes the title is always the bundle display name. The docs aren't completely clear on this:

> If the application is not frontmost and visible, the system displays the alert message, badges the application, and plays a sound—whatever is specified in the notification